Where can I find iridium in Planet Crafter?
In Planet Crafter, I need iridium to craft a food grower. Where can I find iridium?

If you head north from your initial landing site along the mountain, you come across a cave mouth with sand cascading from the top. That cave contains a lot of Iridium (and a mining unit built there can generate more).

How do I know which way is north? You don't unlock the compass until later. :(

Like I said, follow the cliff wall you land near.
